# Get the OpenGL Texture Handle from a SurfaceTexture

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera

SurfaceTexture has a way to set the Texture Handle.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html#attachToGLContext(int)

There doesn't seem to be a way to get the Texture Handle unless you have control over the code that may have set it.

I'm trying to copy the underlying GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES texture to an RGB GL_TEXTURE_2D, for which I need to know the texture Id.  Otherwise I have to just call GetBitmap on the TextureView which ends up doing a GPU to CPU and then back to GPU copy which should be avoidable if I could just copy directly within OpenGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the texture name in your OpenGL ES context by calling `glGenTextures()`, and then call `SurfaceTexture.attachToGLContext(int texName)` to bind the external image to that texture name.

Footnote: once you've done that you can use the SurfaceTexture naively in your shaders by using an external sampler. For most single use algorithms *don't* convert it into a new texture - it's a waste of bandwidth and power.

Comment: Something else already set the texture earlier.  Is it safe to just override what some other process may have set, namely WebRTC?  It may be holding on to the id and I may be breaking some assumptions.  I also have no way to free the original texture handle so we'd potentially be leaking textures.


Is it intentional that there's no getter?  It seems like they're trying very hard to protect SurfaceTexture in a way that makes it impossible to do things at the OpenGL level with it unless I pass it around to other Android View classes or generated the texture ID myself.

Comment: No idea how WebRTC uses the resource, sorry. It certainly sounds like it might be risky if WebRTC is trying to use it as the same time ...

Comment: I guess the solution is to figure out what texture id WebRTC is using if possible.  This is why I wish there was a getter on the SurfaceTexture object itself.

Comment: This wasn't documented very well in the Google docs but this is infact the right thing to do.

I have a better understanding of the GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES.  You don't have write access to it.

Delving into these articles helped me understand this better.  http://www.felixjones.co.uk/neo%20website/Android_View/

Android allows you to render to a Surface which can be associated with a SurfaceTexture.  This Surface can be set as the current EGLSurface.

Afterwards, provided you do this at the right time, you then attach a SurfaceTexture to your context and read from it.

Comment: Ran out of chars:

Basically some OpenGL context writes to a Surface backed by a SurfaceTexture.  Or a camera is attached to a SurfaceTexture.

Then you can have your own arbitrary OpenGL context.  Every time you read it, you generate your own textureId with GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES target and pass that into attachToGLContext.

Afterwards you detach.  This has to be synced right so you're not trying to read while things are writing to it.

Oh also SurfaceTexture can be the EGLSurface directly, not a Surface.